# Without solving directly for the integral, decide if the value of the integral is positve or negative.

Tags: calculus, integration

Sketch the graph of $f(x) = 2x^{3}$ on the interval $[−2,3]$. Shade the signed area represented byZ2 −1 f(x)dx, indicating the regions counted as positive area and negative area. Without actually evaluating the deﬁnite integral, decide if the value of the integral is positive or negative. Brieﬂy explain your answer.
 I am not really sure how to determine if the integral is positive or negative without solving for it.

Comment: We use MathJax to format mathematics on this site.  A tutorial is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  Presumably $f(x)=2x^3$ but I don't know what Z2-1 is supposed to mean.

Comment: *Hint:* By symmetry, what is $\int_{-2}^2 2x^3 \ dx$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having made the sketch, the area above the $x$ axis will be counted positive and the area below the $x$ axis will be counted negative.  You are expected to look at the two areas and figure out which is larger "by eye".